# Polly: Retry request with StreamContent and MemoryStream - no content on second try

Tags: c#, .net, dotnet-httpclient, polly, retry-logic

I'm using `Polly` in combination with `Microsoft.Extensions.Http.Polly` to handle communication with an external API which has rate-limiting (N requests / second).I'm also using .NET 6.

The policy itself works fine for most requests, however it doesn't work properly for sending (stream) data. The API Client requires the usage of `MemoryStream`. When the Polly policy handles the requests and retries it, the stream data is not sent.
I verified this behavior stems from .NET itself with this minimal example:

```
using var fileStream = File.OpenRead(@"C:\myfile.pdf");
using var memoryStream = new MemoryStream();
await fileStream.CopyToAsync(memoryStream);

var response = await httpClient.SendAsync(
    new HttpRequestMessage
    {
        // The endpoint will fail the request on the first request
        RequestUri = new Uri("https://localhost:7186/api/test"),
        Content = new StreamContent(memoryStream),
        Method = HttpMethod.Post
    }
);
```

Inspecting the request I see that `Request.ContentLength` is the length of the file on the first try. On the second try it's 0.

However if I change the example to use the `FileStream` directly it works:

```
using var fileStream = File.OpenRead(@"C:\myfile.pdf");

var response = await httpClient.SendAsync(
    new HttpRequestMessage
    {
        // The endpoint will fail the request on the first request
        RequestUri = new Uri("https://localhost:7186/api/test"),
        Content = new StreamContent(fileStream ),
        Method = HttpMethod.Post
    }
);
```

And this is my `Polly` policy that I add to the chain of `AddHttpClient`.

```
public static IAsyncPolicy<HttpResponseMessage> GetRetryPolicy()
{
    return Policy
        .HandleResult<HttpResponseMessage>(response =>
        {
            return response.StatusCode == System.Net.HttpStatusCode.Forbidden;
        })
        .WaitAndRetryAsync(4, (retry) => TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1));
}
```

**My question:**

How do I properly retry requests where `StreamContent` with a stream of type `MemoryStream` is involved, similar to the behavior of `FileStream`?

**Edit for clarification:**

I'm using an external API Client library (Egnyte) which accepts an instance of `HttpClient`

```
public class EgnyteClient {
   public EgnyteClient(string apiKey, string domain, HttpClient? httpClient = null){
   ...
   }
}
```

I pass an instance which I injected via the `HttpContextFactory` pattern. This instance uses the retry policy from above.

This is my method for writing a file using `EgnyteClient`

```
public async Task UploadFile(string path, MemoryStream stream){
   // _egnyteClient is assigned in the constructor
   await _egnyteClient.Files.CreateOrUpdateFile(path, stream);
}
```

This method call works (doesn't throw an exception) even when the API sometimes returns a 403 statucode  because the internal `HttpClient` uses the Polly retry policy. HOWEVER the data isn't always properly transferred since it just works if it was the first attempt.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The root cause of your problem could be the following: once you have sent out a request then the `MemoryStream`'s `Position` is at the end of the stream. So, any further requests needs to rewind the stream to be able to copy it again into the `StreamContent` (`memoryStream.Position = 0;`).

---

Here is how you can do that with retry:

```
private StreamContent GetContent(MemoryStream ms)
{
   ms.Position = 0;
   return new StreamContent(ms);
}

var response = await httpClient.SendAsync(
    new HttpRequestMessage
    {
        RequestUri = new Uri("https://localhost:7186/api/test"),
        Content = GetContent(memoryStream),
        Method = HttpMethod.Post
    }
);
```

This ensures that the memoryStream has been rewinded for each each retry attempt.

---

**UPDATE #1**
After receiving some clarification and digging in the source code of the Egnyte I think I know understand the problem scope better.

- A 3rd party library receives an `HttpClient` instance which is decorated with a retry policy ([related source code](https://github.com/egnyte/egnyte-dotnet/blob/3b2686b51559465dd2b653564665743fb90d1652/Egnyte.Api/EgnyteClient.cs#L29))
- A `MemoryStream` is passed to a library which is passed forward as a `StreamContent` as a part of an `HttpRequestMessage` ([related source code](https://github.com/egnyte/egnyte-dotnet/blob/3b2686b51559465dd2b653564665743fb90d1652/Egnyte.Api/Files/FilesClient.cs#L56))
- HRM is passed directly to the `HttpClient` and the response is wrapped into a `ServiceResponse` ([related source code](https://github.com/egnyte/egnyte-dotnet/blob/3b2686b51559465dd2b653564665743fb90d1652/Egnyte.Api/Common/ServiceHandler.cs#L18))

Based on the source code you can receive one of the followings:

- An `HttpRequestException` thrown by the `HttpClient`
- An `EgnyteApiException` or `QPSLimitExceededException` or `RateLimitExceededException` thrown by the [`ExceptionHelper`](https://github.com/egnyte/egnyte-dotnet/blob/3b2686b51559465dd2b653564665743fb90d1652/Egnyte.Api/Common/ExceptionHelper.cs#L8)
- An `EgnyteApiException` thrown by the `SendRequestAsync` if there was a problem related to the deserialization
- A `ServiceResponse` from `SendRequestAsync`

As far as I can see you can access the `StatusCode` only if you receive an `HttpRequestException` or an `EgnyteApiException`.

Because you can't rewind the `MemoryStream` whenever an `HttpClient` performs a retry I would suggest to decorate the `UploadFile` with retry. Inside the method you can always set the `stream` parameter's `Position` to 0.

```
public async Task UploadFile(string path, MemoryStream stream){
   stream.Position = 0;
   await _egnyteClient.Files.CreateOrUpdateFile(path, stream);
}
```

So rather than decorating the entire `HttpClient` you should decorate your `UploadFile` method with retry. Because of this you need to alter the policy definition to something like this:

```
public static IAsyncPolicy GetRetryPolicy()
    => Policy
        .Handle<EgnyteApiException>(ex => ex.StatusCode == HttpStatusCode.Forbidden)
        .Or<HttpRequestException>(ex => ex.StatusCode == HttpStatusCode.Forbidden)
        .WaitAndRetryAsync(4, _ => TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1));
```

Maybe the `Or` builder clause is not needed because I haven't seen any `EnsureSuccessStatusCode` call anywhere, but for safety I would build the policy like that.

Comment: That would work if I had control over the method, but I'm using an external API client which accepts a `HttpClient` instance in its constructor. Afterwards I'm calling a method `Task UploadFile(string path, MemoryStream stream)` where I don't control what's happening inside. 
I guess I am looking for a Polly specific thing, like modification of the HttpRequestMessage before sending again.

Comment: @Eddi Sorry but I'm confused. Are you saying that you have control over the registration of the `HttpClient` (w/o policies) but you don't have control over how the `SendAsync` is being called?

Comment: I added a bit more context for clarification to my question.

Comment: @Eddi In your example code you use are using the `MemoryStream` to copy data from `FileStream`. In your `UploadFile` why do you need to pass a filepath and a `MemoryStream` as well?

Comment: @Eddi I've just checked the [source code](https://github.com/egnyte/egnyte-dotnet/blob/3b2686b51559465dd2b653564665743fb90d1652/Egnyte.Api/Files/FilesClient.cs#L56) and now I see how it works. Let me update my post accordingly.

Comment: I tried to show the abstract problem independently of my concrete problem. The excerpt with `FileStream` was to demonstrate that it works with other kind of streams. So again, I imagined that it could be solved by something inside the policy or at least I would imagine that would be the cleanest way to do this. For now I use a workaround and create two separate clients. One client will use the policy. The other will not use it, so that I can wrap it with a separate retry policy.

Comment: @Eddi I've updated my post, please check it.

Comment: I think you came up with the best solution for this scenario. Great answer.